# Recover archive manager's "lost" columns?

Tags: file-roller

Opening an archive, I double-clicked on the "Name" column to expand it since the file names were long, but that made the column disappear.

I tried right clicking and looked for any options and searched the web but I can't seem to be able to find a way to recover the disappeared column. Closing the application as well as restarting doesn't affect this.

Note, I have indicator-appmenu uninstalled. Could it be that the archive manager is supposed to have a menu that I'm not able to see because of this? (I see the menu on every other application).

This is how the archive manager looks like right now:

[image]

The "Properties" field refers to the properties of the archive, not the archive manager.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can not remove the columns in file roller.

What you probably did was make the column zero length.

Get your cursor to the left hand side so that is is 2 arrows pointing left and right. I made a screenshot with the column nearly gone:

[image]

Just drag the cursor to the right to make the column larger.

Comment: Right, the width had become zero!

Comment: Oh my god! I was struggling to find a solution for days!

Comment: @Ranveer yeah well it had me stumped too back then :D

Answer (score 3):

The following command resets the margin width for file name in file-roller:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.FileRoller.Listing name-column-width
```

([source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187251))